# Why I can't run any docker commands inside my Jenkins Docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

In my EC2 instance, I created a docker image from a running Jenkins container to get the existing jobs to the new image. Then I ran the new image with a different port mapping. Then when I enter inside the new container and ran `docker ps`. But i got an error like below

```
root@6151a7f83e0f:/# docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
root@6151a7f83e0f:/#
```

Then I tried to start docker inside the new container with this sudo service docker start. But I received below error,

```
etc/init.d/docker: 96: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
```

What am I missing here?

FYI, above commands are working fine in the old container. FYI, the whole purpose of this work is to migrate Jenkins from one instance to another without creating a fresh Jenkins container.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the old container is running with a different user other than the `root`. Normally Jenkins will create a new user called Jenkins. If so switch to the correct user from root and try to execute the commands.

**Update:** I assume you created the image from a running EC2 instance without rebooting. There can be issues if you do so. AWS page has a Warning for this. Check the below.

[image]

Comment: the old container is also running with root user
ubuntu@ip-10-133-184-39:~$ docker exec -it 76df6fa99373 bash
root@76df6fa99373:/# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
76df6fa99373        623f146580dd        "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   19 months ago       Up 41 hours         0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   jenkins

Comment: In that case, the image may be corrupted. Check the updated answer.

Comment: FYI, i created the image using docker commit command and pushed it to ECR. Then pulled the image from ECR in to my new EC2. As per your saying, do I need to recreate the image after rebooting the old instance?

Comment: In that case, my comment is not relevant. I thought you created an AWS AMI based on a running Instance. Can you do a docker inspect <CONTAINER_ID> and compare the two running images and see what's different?